# Why XMLHttpRequest status 0 with this link?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, status

I am trying to retrieve some JSON data from a link using javascript. Yet, I am getting status = 0, and I have no idea why. This always worked for me, but now I just get an empty response. I can retrieve the data normally in a browser, so I tried setting the UA header without luck. Maybe I should set another header??

This is my method to retrieve the data:

```
function retrieveBusData(bus) {
  var file = "https:....";
  var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhReq.timeout = 50000;
  xhReq.ontimeout = function() { console.log("#########--- " + getsecs() + " - TIMEOUT en retrieveBusData"); };
  xhReq.open("GET", file, true);
  xhReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhReq.status != 200) {
      printbondiinfo("X");
    } else {
      if (xhReq.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhReq.responseText)
          processData(xhReq.responseText);
        else
          printbondiinfo("??");
      }   
    } 
  } 
  xhReq.send(null);
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @epascarello for pointing me the CORS problem. Indeed, I can see in the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jeap.rio...' from origin 'null'
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: how is retrieveBusData called? My guess is you do not cancel the button/link's action.

Comment: In a loop when starting the script. retrieveBusData is being called properly, it just returns empty.

Comment: No... what triggers it. Something starts it off. Or it is a CORS error. What is in the developer console?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. The script is inside a webpage. As soon as you open the page, a script starts a loop executed once each minute, and each time the function is called to retrieve the data.

Comment: Your developer console most likely has the error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jeap.rio.rj.gov.br/dadosAbertosAPI/v2/transporte/veiculos/onibus2/409' from origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Basically the site has not set headers so you can not read it. Open your developer console and look for the error messages

Comment: Yes, I see it. I tried adding `xhReq.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` without luck. What else can I do? If a browser can retrieve, so does javascript... no?

Comment: If a 3rd party site does not add it, there is nothing you can do in the clientside javascript to access it. That is how CORS works.

Comment: @epascarello I used a simple php workaround. Please check my answer.

Comment: So you used a proxy which is a work around CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I used `php` as a workaround. I created a simple `simple.php` file in my own page with this content:

```
<?php 
  file_get_contents('https://<stupid file without Access-Control-Allow-Origin header>');
?>
```

and then I changed the corresponding javascript `file` line for the `XMLHttpRequest` with

```
...
var file = "https://<my site>/simple.php";
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", file, true);
...
```

In this way, the javascript `XMLHttpRequest` is made to a page **with** `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set (through my own `.htaccess` file), and `php` does not care about the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.